# Python Azure Function, queue-triggered alternative `connection` for `function.json`?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

Is there a way to use a Managed Identity (either System or User-assigned) for authenticating a Function and Storage Account?

**Example**

- In a Python Azure Function's `function.json` file, there is a `bindings` object:

```
"bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "<my-queue-name>",
      "connection": "CONN_STRING"
    }
  ]
```

- The `connection` parameter refers to a `value` in `local.settings.json` when run locally OR an `App Setting` when deployed to Azure.
- These can be either hardcoded in these areas or use a Key Vault Secret Reference

**Question**:

- Instead of using a Connection String (whether KV Reference or not), can I can grant the Functions Managed Identity a `Storage Queue Contributor` RBAC role?
- I don't want to handle these Connection Strings

Is this possible? If so, what value do I put in the `connection` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Instead of using a Connection String (whether KV Reference or not), can I can grant the Functions Managed Identity a  `Storage Queue Contributor`  RBAC role?

Instead of passing the *Storage Account's connection string*, you can achieve the same with an ***Identity-Based connection***. Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob&pivots=programming-language-python#connecting-to-host-storage-with-an-identity):

You can use `AzureWebJobsStorage__queueServiceUri` setting to achieve your requirement.

- You must have **`Storage Queue Data Contributor`** role.

[image]

- Assign `Storage Queue Data Reader` and `Storage Queue Data Message Processor` roles in the Storage Account.
- Enable **Managed Identity** in the Function App.
- Set the Application Setting in the `local.setting.json` `AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName` to the name of the your storage account as its value.

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage__queueServiceUri": "https://<your_storage_account_name>.queue.core.windows.net/"
  }
}
```

**function_app.py:**

```py
app = func.FunctionApp()


@app.queue_trigger(arg_name="azqueue", queue_name="<queuename>",
                               connection="AzureWebJobsStorage") 
def queue_trigger(azqueue: func.QueueMessage):
    logging.info('Python Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                azqueue.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

**Local Response:**

```
(.venv) C:\Users\username\pythonazfn>func host start
Found Python version 3.11.6 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554

[2023-12-11T12:24:54.722Z] Customer packages not in sys path. This should never happen!
[2023-12-11T12:24:58.257Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        queue_trigger: queueTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-12-11T12:25:02.978Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000xXXXXCC'.
[2023-12-11T12:25:31.670Z] Executing 'Functions.queue_trigger' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'queue123'.', Id=b7a1a111-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-769bbd7ace88)
[2023-12-11T12:25:31.677Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 84b783dd-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX04ae2656b, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2023-12-11T12:25:12.000+00:00
[2023-12-11T12:25:31.817Z] Python Queue trigger processed a message: Hello world
[2023-12-11T12:25:31.891Z] Executed 'Functions.queue_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=b7a1a111-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-769bbd7ace88, Duration=310ms)
```

**Updated Solution:**

To use an identity-based connection to a Storage Account which is not the AzureWebJobsStorage Account, assign the storage account as value to any new variable with pattern  `"<CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__queueServiceUri": "https://<storage_account_name>.queue.core.windows.net"`

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "QueueConn__queueServiceUri": "https://<your_storage_account_name>.queue.core.windows.net/"
  }
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

Change the **connection value** in the `functionapp.py` as `connection =<CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>`.

```py
app = func.FunctionApp()


@app.queue_trigger(arg_name="azqueue", queue_name="<queuename>",
                               connection="QueueConn") 
def queue_trigger(azqueue: func.QueueMessage):
    logging.info('Python Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                azqueue.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Two questions for you: **1.)** I see you are using the v2 Azure Function pattern. Does this apply to v1 as well? **2.)** The Storage Queue is in another Storage Account, *not* the same Account as `AzureWebJobsStorage`. Does this matter?

Comment: Hm...this isn't working for me. I think its because the Storage Queue that triggers the Function, is NOT hosted in the `AzureWebJobsStorage` Storage Account. I have two Storage Accounts. 1 just to host the Azure Function (`AzureWebJobsStorage`) and 1 to store blobs and the queues that trigger the Azure Function. Could you show how to use an identity-based connection to a Storage Account that is **not** the `AzureWebJobsStorage` Account?

Comment: Please check the updated solution.